# Other fruit cider BJCP question

Tags: cider, fruit, bjcp

Good afternoon, guy!

I've been planning to make a specialty cider and have been looking into **"28B. Fruit Cider"** of 2008 guide or **"40B. Cider with Other Fruit"** of 2014 version.

One thing I don't really get is what is it... Does it mean that I have to use apple juice as primary source of sugar and other fruits (like apricot) for the taste, or can I just use apricot juice and still call it an **other fruit cider**?

If I have to use apple juice, what proportion is appropriate, like 51%/49%? I'm asking it from BJCP point of view. If I eventually make something worth drinking, and enter it into one of the competition, I don't want to be disqualified. :)

Sorry if it is a dumb question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer to your first question is under the Flavor/Aroma section:

*The cider character must be present and must fit with the other fruits. It is a fault if the added fruit(s) completely dominate; a judge might ask, “Would this be different if neutral spirits replaced the cider?” A fruit cider should not be like an alco-pop.*

And, under overall impression:

*Like a white wine with complex flavors. The apple character must marry with the added fruit so that neither one dominates the other*

Basically, this description is saying that the beverage should taste like apple cider with other fruit flavors blending in. That would be difficult to achieve without using some apple juice. As for the ratio, I think it depends on what the other fruit is, and how prominent its flavor is when compared to apple. When I am trying to brew a style for the first time, I usually search the web for recipes and look for common guidance on the proportion of ingredients.

Note that this is a relatively subjective category. Judges are looking for balance and a pleasant taste, and the parameters are not nearly as strict as they are for most of the styles. Part of the fun of homebrewing is experimentation -- brew a batch, and see how you like it. You can tweak the ingredients on the next round to improve it.

Comment: Great respond! That is why I wanna play with this category. I'll make 2 gallons of apple cider and 2 gallons of fruit wine. I'll start blending to find the perfect ratio. That is a fun part of brewing.